# How To fire POST Request with params and token

Tags: web-services, rest-assured

I am new to API testing with jayway RestAssured.
my jmeter url : http://ip:8080/servelet?token=toekntext&methodname={jsontext}
above url is POST Request, i need to fire request in jayway RestAsseured.
url = http://ip:8080/servelet

Response r = given().contentType(CONTENT_TYPE).accept(CONTENT_ACCEPT).headers("user-agent", web).queryParam("token", tokentext).queryParam("methodname", jsonttext).expect().statusCode(200).when().post(url);

Is the above code correct to fire POST Request Here i am getting 500 internal server error, plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that looks right given that it truly are query parameters that JMeter is sending. I suspect that it might not be since it's very unusual in my experience that include JSON (I assume `jsontext` is JSON) in the request path. Try switching from `queryParam` to `formParam` to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: thank you Johan for ur replay i have tried like this Response r = given().contentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8).accept("application/json").headers("user-agent", web)
    .param("token", tokentext).formParam("methodname", JSON)
    .expect().statusCode(200).when().post(url); still showing 500 internal server error.

Comment: Doesn't the server give any more clues (logs etc) of WHY a 500 page is generated?

Comment: in server logs, getting methodname and token as null

Answer (score 0):

Try restructuring your code,
FULL-URL - url/account?token=TOKEN&sync=TRUE, then you can try post request as below

```
given().
contentType(ContentType.JSON).body(payload).
queryParam("token", "TOKEN").
queryParam("sync", "TRUE").
when().post(url).then().
statusCode(200).extract().response();
```

Comment: Thanks Anoop, Both queryParam, body, we cant combine in request. throwing error if i pass both.

Comment: The cliche dialogue - this works on my machine,  but only difference in your request I can see is, you send application type in different way and also you send headers. If those are not important lets try above way.

Comment: Hi Anoop, By taking jmeter url, i am framing the url as  url = http://ip:8080/servelet, actually i am signing up here. jmeter url : http://ip:8080/servelet?token=toekntext&addUser={"fname":"subhash",
 "lname":"subhash1",}, by using this i need to fire a request using rest-assured. here i am trying as Response r = given().contentType(CONTENT_TYPE).accept(CONTENT_ACCEPT).headers("user-agent", web)
    .queryParam("token", tokentext).formParam("addUser", true).body({"fname":"subhash",
 "lname":"subhash1",})
    .expect().statusCode(200).when().post(url); is this correct